# Disable downloads for a browser in android

Tags: android, android-browser, android-download-manager

I am using fennec(Morzilla browser) in my android application. In this application if i select to disable downloads it must disable the downloads in the browser as well. How can i do that?

Answer (score 2):

You can ask the Mozilla team if they offer an API to control this. I doubt that they do. Moreover, there are many, many other browsers available for Android, few (if any) of which will allow random apps from random developers to unilaterally decide to "disable the downloads".

Comment: Is it possible for me to get control of the starting of download?

Answer (score 1):

I highly doubt you can do that. As [CommonsWare](https://stackoverflow.com/users/115145/commonsware) said, I doubt that Mozilla offers such an API.

Also, I don't really understand how you're using Mozilla in your app. When launching an Intent, usually the user will be prompted to choose from the apps that can achieve that particular request, unless you direct the Intent to the exact package of the app.

Maybe there's a design-related way around this issue for you that will save you a lot of time and headaches.

Comment: I Just want to control the download option in the browser. Disable and enable it accordingly. Any procedure to get the control of download starting?

Comment: I think giving other apps access to starting or disabling a browser's downloads would be quite the security flaw, I think. Maybe you can have the browser open towards a really simple page coded in .php or something similar in which you push the download to the connected device and let the Browser handle it accordingly. There are other, more elegant ways to manage downloads in your app by completely avoiding browsers.